# UWP The name XXX does not exist in the namespace "using:AAA"

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I created a folder name "common" under my project.
In this folder, I created a file named DataToStringConverter.cs
Before using this source as a StaticResource, I linked it as below.
But this error always happens.
"the name "DataToStringConverter" does not exist in the namespace "using:MyFirstApp.common" "

Am I missing something in the settings?

App.xaml

```
<Application
    x:Class="MyFirstApp.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MyFirstApp"
    xmlns:common="using:MyFirstApp.common">

    <Application.Resources>
        
        <common:DataToStringConverter x:Key="DateTimeConverter"/>  **error line at here**
        
    </Application.Resources>

</Application>
```

DataToStringConverter.cs

```
namespace MyFirstApp.common
{
    public class DataToStringConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
             throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
             throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

I cleaned solution and rebuild, but not works

Comment: A USING block can only be used in a method.  Either the USING block is not properly terminated or the USING statement at top of module is missing a semicolon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created the `DataToStringConverter` class according to your steps and found that you missed `throw` when implementing the interface `IValueConverter`. I also get [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95toz.png) `DataToStringConverter.Convert(object, Type, object, string)': not all code paths return a value`

After adding `throw`,the resource can access `DataToStringConverter`.

```
public class DataToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Junjie Zhu ,  sorry, I omitted "new", but error as the title is not solved.  :(

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what happened; it is like a "magic mirror".

In `DataToStringConverter.cs`, I changed `namespace MyFirstApp.common` to `namespace MyFirstApp`, then cleaned rebuilt the solution. After that, it's OK.

Then I reverted namespace `MyFirstApp` to `MyFirstApp.common`,
cleaned and rebuilt the solution, and this error is solved.

Is it a Visual Studio bug?

Comment: I don't think this is a visual studio bug, if you don't omit `throw new NotImplementedException();` when implementing `IValueConverter`, then `DataToStringConverter` will be compiled successfully and there will be no error when accessed. I followed the right steps to implement the interface `IValueConverter `at the very beginning and everything worked fine. Then I checked what's the difference between us and I saw that you omit `throw`, when I use your code, I get the same error as you.

Comment: In fact, don't care about this `throw new NotImplementedException`, it will throw an error alerting you that section of your code isn't complete yet. You can implement the function you want in `Convert` and `ConvertBack`.